# How can I avoiding Cartesian product on SQL on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join, cartesian-product

Here is my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/671c8/1.

Here are my tables:

Person

`PID    LNAME   FNAME
1       Bob     Joe
2       Smith   John
3       Johnson Jake
4       Doe     Jane`

Table1

`PID    VALUE
1       3
1       5
1       35
2       10
2       15
3       8`

Table2

`PID    VALUE
1       X1
1       X2
1       X3
2       Z1
3       X3`

I am trying to join several tables on a person's ID. These tables contain events with dates, but the dates may or may not match across table. So what I really want it to regardless of date join the tables in a way such that when I get results the table with the largest rows will be the amount of rows in my result and all other tables will "fit" within. For example

Instead of this which is a cartesian product:

```
PID     LNAME   FNAME   THINGONE    THINGTWO
1       Bob     Joe     3           X1
1       Bob     Joe     3           X2
1       Bob     Joe     3           X3
1       Bob     Joe     5           X1
1       Bob     Joe     5           X2
1       Bob     Joe     5           X3
1       Bob     Joe     35          X1
1       Bob     Joe     35          X2
1       Bob     Joe     35          X3
```

I would like something like this:

```
PID     LNAME   FNAME   THINGONE    THINGTWO
1       Bob     Joe     3           X1
1       Bob     Joe     5           X2
1       Bob     Joe     35          X3
```

My sql statement:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    t1.value as thingone,
    t2.value as thingtwo
FROM
    person p 
    left outer join table1 t1 on p.pid=t1.pid
    left outer join table2 t2 on p.pid=t2.pid
;
```

Comment: Would be nice if you posted your tables in a more "readable" way

Comment: What is the relationship between table2 and table3 besides pid? Otherwise, there will be a Cartesian join between these two tables.

Comment: Relationship between table1 and table2 is missing, thats why its giving you cartesian join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't fathom *why* you want to do this, but...

You need to create an artificial join between table1 and table2, and then link that to the master table. One way of doing that is by ranking the rows in order. eg:

```
SELECT 
    p.pid, p.lname,p.fname, thingone, thingtwo
FROM
    person p 
    left outer join 
    (
        select ISNULL(t1.pid, t2.pid) as pid, t1.value as thingone, t2.value as thingtwo
        from 
            (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pid order by value) rn 
                     from table1) t1 
            full outer join 
                    (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pid order by value) rn 
                     from table2) t2 
                    on t1.pid=t2.pid and t1.rn=t2.rn
    ) v
        on p.pid = v.pid
```

Comment: This answer handles the case where there is a value in one table and not in the other at a certain "event" a bit better (keeping it null). I don't think I could do this for many thing tables though...

Comment: I chose to modify your answer a bit, I think this does it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0b423/42 if anyone cares to improve performance or readability let please go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a trickier problem than I thought.  The challenge is being sure that all the records appear, regardless of the lengths of the two lists.  The following works by enumerating each of the lists and using that for the join conditions:

```
SELECT p.*,
       t1.value as thingone,
       t2.value as thingtwo
FROM person p left outer join
     (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pid order by pid) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by pid) as cnt
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on p.pid = t1.pid left outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by pid order by pid) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by pid) as cnt
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on p.pid = t2.pid
WHERE t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum or
      (t2.seqnum > t1.cnt) or
      (t1.seqnum > t2.cnt) or
      t1.seqnum is null or
      t2.seqnum is null;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cfb9/10) is a slight modification to your SQL Fiddle that has better test data.

EDIT:

The logic in the `where` clause handles these cases (in order by the clauses):

1. Where the two lists have sequence numbers, these must match.
2. Where list2 is longer and list1 has at least one element.
3. Where list1 is longer and list2 has at least one element.
4. Where list1 is empty
5. Where list 2 is empty

These were arrived at by trial and error, because the original condition did not work:

```
     on p.pid = t2.pid and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
```

This returns `NULL` values for `p.id` for the extra elements on the list.  Podliuska's approach may also work; I had just started down this path and the `where` conditions do the trick.

Comment: I see now that I need the row_number, but could you explain a bit what is the logic on the WHERE statements?

Comment: If I had to do this for more than three tables, for example thing3, thing4, etc.. The where clause would get pretty huge/nasty right? as I would have to do that logic check between all tables.

Comment: Basically I can join the person table against each thing table individually, but I would like to do it against all thing tables, but it seems the query will get out of hand quick with more thing tables.

Comment: @zweettooth . . . Generalizing to multiple tables doesn't seem to be part of the question.  Maybe it is buried in there, but you quite explicitly start with "Here are my tables" and then list three tables.